# Async event handlers and concurency

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

In the context of a C# console application, if I make a loop used to receive message asynchronously which raises an event for each message received, such as :

```
while (true)
{
   var message = await ReceiveMessageAsync();
   ReceivedMessage(new ReceivedMessageEventArgs(message));
}
```

Now if I have multiple subscribers to the event (let's say 3 subscribers for the sake of the example), all of them using an asynchronous event handler such as :

```
async void OnReceivedMessageAsync(object sender, ReceivedMessageEventArgs args)
{
   await TreatMessageAsync(args.Message);
}
```

Should message object be coded in a thread safe way ? I think so, as TreatMessageAsync code from the different event handlers may run concurently for all the subscribers (when event is raised, the three async event handlers of the subscribers are called, each launching an async operation which potentially could be run concurently on different threads by the task scheduler). Or am I wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: You haven't given us enough detail here - there's no indication of what `TreatMessageAsync` is, or what the event is. If you could give a short but *complete* program, that would make life a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should code it in a thread-safe way. The easiest way to do so is to make it immutable.

If you have a true *event*, then its arguments should be immutable. If you're using an event handler for something that's not a true *event* (like a *command* or *implementation*) then you may want to modify your API.

It is possible to have concurrent event handlers because each handler will *start* sequentially, but they can *resume* concurrently.

Comment: Thank for the clear answer and sorry for the delay for marking it as answered. After some reflexion I realized that it wasn't the correct way to go .. I was indeed using an event handler for something that was not a "true event". I modified my prototype accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As Stephen suggested the easiest way to achieve thread-safety in this case is to use immutable event args.

In most cases even args are used only to notify observers without any requirements for changes from observable side to observer (i.e. from event subscriber to event owner). In some special cases like implementing Chains of Responsibility design pattern event args should be mutable but in all other case they shouldn't.

Immutability in this case helps you not only implement concurrent handlers easily but lead to more clear design and improves maintainability because now one have an ability to use your API incorrectly.

**The conclusion is**: you should implement your methods thread-safety but you should aware that unhandled exception from event handler will be swallowed if your event will be fired from non-UI thread.

Here is a danger of using async void methods: if this method will fail with exception and you'll call it in the environment without synchronization context (like from thread pool thread of from console application), you'll get domain unhandled exception you application will close:

```
internal class Program
{
    static Task Boo()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            throw new Exception("111");
                        });
    }

    private static async void Foo()
    {
        await Boo();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Application will blow with DomainUnhandled excpeption!
        try
        {
            Foo();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Will not catch it here!
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not quite. As with any async void method, the handlers will start sequentially and continue asynchronously as soon as they yield. The void return type means that the sender will be unable to await all handlers even if it wanted to. From the doc at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx "The caller of a void-returning async method can't await it and can't catch exceptions that the method throws."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "The caller of a void-returning method ... can't catch exceptions that the method throws" is only true for the code after the fist await of the void method. Any exceptions thrown before the first await can be caught by the caller.

Comment: That's a quote from the documentation. It is already explained at the link provided (right after the first code sample)

Comment: @FrancoisNel: That was true during the original Async CTP. In the first CTP refresh, that [behavior was changed to be more consistent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2011/04/15/async-ctp-refresh-design-changes.aspx). The MSDN documentation correctly describes `async` behavior in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: Exceptions from `async void` event handlers aren't swallowed; they just can't be caught. They pass directly to the `SynchronizationContext` and are raised there.

Comment: @StephenCleary: and what if we don't have sync context?

Comment: @SergeyTeplyakov: then they are raised on the default (thread pool) `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: @StephenCleary: see my code sample for more details. Trying to use such method in console app will blow it up with DomainUnhandled exception. BTW, thread pool `SynchronizationContext` is equals to null.

Comment: `DomainUnhandled` is the opposite of "swallowed". "Swallowed" means "ignored".

Comment: @StephenCleary: Agreed. My bad, actually I expected task onobserved exception instead of domain unhandled exception. But anyway developer should be aware of such behavior.

Comment: thanks for the comments, quite interesting ! 
+1 for your answer Sergey.